# String to time returning empty

Tags: php, string, datetime, strtotime

I have a function that strips the slashes out of users date input to make it in the format `ddmmYYYY` format.

```
function mydate($input)
{
    $sanitized = preg_replace("/[^0-9A-Za-z\:\- ]/", "", $input);
    return $sanitized;
}
```

I got another function that checks that the date is before the after that

```
function datebefore($before,$after)
{

    $before = substr($before,2,2)."-".substr($before,0,2)."-".substr($before,4,4);
    $after = substr($after,2,2)."-".substr($after,0,2)."-".substr($after,4,4);


    return strtotime($after)." > ".strtotime($before) ; 

    /* if(strtotime($after) < strtotime($before) )
    {
        return "The start date is after the end";
    } */
}
```

Issue Im having is that when the before or after date is a more than 1 day before the current date it returns a empty string rather than a timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime` depends upon the seperator to decide what the date format you are using is.

If the seperator is `-` it assumes a sensible date format `dd/mm/yyyy`, if it is `/` it assumes an American date format `mm-dd-yyyy`.

So your issue is the seperator you used. Change the format to `dd-mm-yyyy` and reorganise the order of your d,m, and y vaues and it will be fine

```
function datebefore($start,$end)
{

    $s = sprintf('%s-%s-%s',  substr($start,0,2), substr($start,2,2), substr($start,4,4));
    $e = sprintf('%s-%s-%s', substr($end,0,2), substr($end,2,2), substr($end,4,4));

    return strtotime($s) > strtotime($e) 
                ? 'The start date is after the end' 
                : 'The start date is before the end'; 
}

function mydate($input)
{
    $sanitized = preg_replace("/[^0-9A-Za-z\:\- ]/", "", $input);
    return $sanitized;
}

$s = mydate('10/12/2016');
echo $s . PHP_EOL;
$e = mydate('06/12/2016');
echo $e . PHP_EOL;

$c = datebefore($s, $e);
echo $c;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.strtotime.php) not accept you time string format, then it return false.

You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/zh/datetime.createfromformat.php) replace of strtotime to create datetime, then use opeator > to compare.

as:

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', '11012017'));
```

Comment: Link only answer are discouraged on SO